# Not able to hit the meteor app server using Jmeter

Tags: node.js, testing, meteor, jmeter, load-testing

Required a quick help.

I am preparing a load testing script in jmeter which is hitting the meteor app server.

The problem is that, all the requests are executing without any error but in the server we have a option to see how many request are being hit to the server ,but that counter is not increasing and not able to hit the request.

[image]

[image]

so in above image you can see the connection tab which shows the no. of user currently active, i am hitting more than 50 users but still counter is not getting increased.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to share your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration but looking at my crystal ball I can assume that you have only 1 iteration so each virtual users executes a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) (or Samplers) and is being shut down.

If you want concurrency - you need to set higher number of iterations so the users which have been started already would continue holding the load while others are ramping up, example setup:

[image]

More information: [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected)